# How to perform Update in DynamoDB without sql-like UpdateExpression?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a very generic implementation of a Database class in my application.

I'd like to feed two things to the AWS DynamoDB Update: `id` and `data {...}` to be updated.

However, I only see the following SQL-like method in the docs:

```
{
    TableName: "Music",
    Key: {
        "Artist":"No One You Know",
        "SongTitle":"Call Me Today"
    },
    UpdateExpression: "SET RecordLabel = :label",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":label": "Global Records"
    }
}
```

Is there really no way whatsoever to do this more MongoDB-style, without having to actually write queries? I would be looking more into something like this:

```
{
    TableName: "Music",
    Key: {
        "id":"123-random-id"
    },
    Item: { "label": "Global Records" }
}
```

Unfortunately while this doesn't fail, it doesn't update anything.

Comment: I've updated to generate those attributes dynamically. But I still wonder whether it has an easier to use API like MongoDB.

Comment: You might want to check out [PartiQL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.update.html), it's a SQL-like language for NoSQL databases by AWS and DynamoDB support has been added recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar enough with MongoDB to compare its query syntax to DynamoDB.
However, if I understand your question correctly, you are asking if there isn't a simpler way to work with the DynamoDB API.  In my experience, the answer to that question is No.  Well, not using the AWS SDK directly.

There are several efforts in the community to build tooling that makes interaction with DynamoDB feel more natural.  [DynamoDB Toolbox](https://github.com/jeremydaly/dynamodb-toolbox) is one such effort that has worked well for me, although it does not shield you from understanding the syntax of DynamoDB expressions.

For example, with DynamoDB Toolbox, your example code snippet could be written as:

```
let item = {
   id: "123-random-id",
   label: "Global Records",
}
await MyEntity.update(item)
```

Comment: That looks very promising! Coming from MongoDB and switching to DynamoDB for my current project, I feel spoiled with the MongoDB abstractions! With MongoDB for gets, you don't have to worry about keys for example. You just pass in an object, and all those fields need to match in the results. For the update, you also just pass an object with the fields to be updated, no need to write any kind of expressions. The toolbox get looks nice, but I wonder if it only works on key items, or also on non-key items? I'll have to play a bit with it.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't explain what you hoped `Item: { "label": "Global Records" }` would do:

If you want to replace the *entire* item, you can do with with a [PutItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html).

However, if what you wanted to do is to only replace the `label` attribute of the item, and not touch any of the other existing attributes of the item, then you really need to use `UpdateItem` like you did. You can either use the `UpdateExpression` syntax as you did - which isn't too hard, honestly - but there is also an older syntax [AttributeUpdates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html#DDB-UpdateItem-request-AttributeUpdates) which you may like better because you just need to define the attributes you want to replace - without preparing an "expression". The AttributeUpdates syntax is older and considered "legacy" but still works, and many applications use it so I doubt it will go away any time soon.